# How can I remove the first n characters from a string in swift?

Tags: swift

I've tried many options but I can't solve it. I've URLs of differents sizes within string variables. I need just remove the http:// from them. How can I do it in Swift?

Comment: Don't work with URLs as strings. De-serialize them into `URL` instances as soon as you get them, and re-serialize them back into `String` instances at the last possible moment. Doing raw string manipulations to work with URLs is incredibly error prone, and frankly, it's just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. In my case I have the URLs in an array configured with them manually by me. Then, I make connection test to these URLs and finally I need remove the http:// from them to show them in the screen. It is something simple and without risk I think. I will take your recommendation in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of removing n characters you maybe want to specifically check for `http(s)://`:

```
let string = "https://www.google.de"
let newString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "https?://", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Or:

```
var str = "https://www.google.de"
if let httpRange = str.range(of: "https?://", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) {
    str.removeSubrange(httpRange)
}
```

Comment: Thanks André for your answer. I've implemented the Sandeep's answer first that is shorter.

Comment: It may be shorter but it's less safe.

Answer (score 0):

To most reliably remove the scheme from the URL, I would avoid hard coding the scheme:

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "http://google.com")!

var string = url.absoluteString
if let scheme = url.scheme, string.hasPrefix(scheme) {
    string.removeFirst(scheme.count + "://".count)
}

print(string)
```